# Use of 'following-sibling' in XQuery function to return TIME element if a specific pattern is matched

Tags: xml, xquery, saxon

I am attempting to write a function in XQuery that returns me a timestamp from an XML data sequence if a specific pattern of values is detected. The data is actually a test log of a system's api messages

The sample XML data looks similar to the snippet below. If the sequence is found it is assumed that the timestamp (TIME tag) will be the same for each line of the pattern  entry.

The specific pattern I need to detect & return the `TIME` of - is where there are four `<FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>VALID</MODE>` entries in sequence followed directly by four `<FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>MULTI</MODE>` entries in sequence - all with the same timestamp.

```
<SEQUENCE><TIME>13.00</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>INVALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>13.00</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>INVALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>13.00</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>SINGLE</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>13.00</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>SINGLE</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>13.00</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>SINGLE</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>13.00</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>SINGLE</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>VALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>VALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>VALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>VALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>MULTI</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>MULTI</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>MULTI</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>MULTI</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>15.94</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>INVALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>
<SEQUENCE><TIME>15.94</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>INVALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>
```

The function I have attempted to define is as follows but gives run time error with `'empty sequence not allowed'`. Unfortunately I do not have an IDE where I can set a break point and debug this - I am thinking I can not use following-sibling once I have selected an entry with a `FOR`.

```
declare function local:get_multi_track_sequence_time( $msgSeq as element()*) as xs:double {
    for $row in $msgSeq
    where some $entry in $row satisfies($entry/SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID']
                    /following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID']
                    /following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID']
                    /following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID']
                    /following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI']
                    /following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI']
                    /following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI']
                    /following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI'] )
    return data($row/SEQUENCE/TIME)
};
```

Thanks. I am a relative newby to XQuery.

---------------------**EDIT - ADDED TEST FUNCTION WITH IDEAS FROM SUGGESTIONS**---------------------

Thanks for the suggestions already received. I have written the following self contained test function based on the helpful information given - the function is unable to match following-sibling's.

The function creates a variable `data` that contains the test sequence. The function as it stands returns an empty sequence. The requirement is that it returns `14.050000` to indicate the scalar `TIME` at which there are four `<FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>VALID</MODE>` entries in sequence followed directly by four `<FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>MULTI</MODE>` entries in sequence (i.e. at TIME `14.050000` in the test data).

(Interestingly it successfully returns a sequence of doubles if only the first expression is used i.e. matches all occurrences of TRACK_STATUS/VALID no following-sibling matches are specified.)

```
declare function local:get_multi_track_sequence_time( ) as xs:double* {

    let $data as element()* := (

<SEQUENCE><TIME>13.04080</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>INVALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>13.04080</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>INVALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>13.05000</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>VALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>13.06900</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>SINGLE</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>13.06900</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>SINGLE</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05000</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>VALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05000</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>VALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05000</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>VALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05000</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>TRACK_STATUS</FIELD><MODE>VALID</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05000</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>MULTI</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05000</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>MULTI</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05000</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>MULTI</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>14.05000</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>MULTI</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>15.06700</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>SINGLE</MODE></SEQUENCE>,
<SEQUENCE><TIME>15.06700</TIME><TAG>2900</TAG><FIELD>MULTI_CHAN_IND</FIELD><MODE>SINGLE</MODE></SEQUENCE>

)

    for $entry in $data
    where $entry/self::SEQUENCE
            [TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID']
          /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
            [TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID']
          /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
            [TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID']
          /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
            [TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID']
          /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
            [TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI']
          /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
            [TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI']
          /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
            [TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI']
          /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
            [TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI']

    return data($entry/TIME)
};
```

Comment: It appears to me that your `<SEQUENCE>` elements are not siblings (they are separate items in a sequence), so `following-sibling::` won't work. To make them siblings, wrap them in a parent element, e.g. `<root>`, and remove the commas between them.

Comment: Thanks @LarsH - will make the correction and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the following working function that gives the correct scalar time in the first value in returned sequence.

```
declare function local:get_multi_track_sequence_times( $msgSeq as element()* ) as xs:double* {
    let $data := (<ROOT>{$msgSeq}</ROOT>)
    let $s1 := $data/SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID'],
        $s2 := $s1/following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID'],
        $s3 := $s2/following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID'],    
        $s4 := $s3/following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID'],    
        $s5 := $s4/following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI'],
        $s6 := $s5/following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI'],
        $s7 := $s6/following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI'],
        $s8 := $s7/following-sibling::SEQUENCE[TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI']

    return $s8/TIME           
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close to succeeding.

A few things need cleaning up.  First, the combination of `for $row in $msgSeq` and `some $entry in $row` are iterating over the same sequence of elements (the sequence passed in as `$msgSeq`).  It's not clear from your question what you're passing in as the value of $msgSeq, but I wonder if you mean `where some $entry in $row/*` or (exploiting the implicit existential quantification) just `where $row/*/SEQUENCE ...`.

Second, your problem description suggests you want to find (parents of) sequences of eight adjacent SEQUENCE elements with certain properties.  But your long XPath expression does not require adjacency:  `$foo/following-sibling::SEQUENCE` matches *all* following siblings of $foo named SEQUENCE.  To constrain the path to make the items adjacent, you need to change the steps of the form

```
.../following-sibling::SEQUENCE[ ... conditions ... ]
```

to

```
.../following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE[ ... ]
```

If the following sibling is guaranteed to be a SEQUENCE, of course, this could be made shorter, at the possible cost of losing some clarity.

Third, your declaration says you're returning exactly one double.  But the function body isn't guaranteed to return exactly one double, so a strict static type analysis by a pessimistic processor might well reject it.  The things I see first off are:

- If $row contains more than one SEQUENCE element, then `data($row/SEQUENCE/TIME)` is going to return more than one TIME value, not just one.  If you're quite confident that all the SEQUENCE/TIME values will be the same, adding `[1]` is a way to ensure this expression returns at most one value, not (say) eight or twenty.
- When nothing matches, your function actually returns the empty sequence, not a single sequence of one double.
- If more than one $row in $msgSeq satisfies the condition, you'll return the sequence of results formed by evaluating `data($row/SEQUENCE/TIME)` for each $row that satisfies the conditions.  The shape of your data may guarantee that this will never ever happen, but the static analyser is unlikely to know that.

The revised form of your function given below assumes (a) that $msgSeq is a sequence of SEQUENCE elements, and (b) that you want to find every SEQUENCE element which is the first event in the event sequence you describe, and return its time stamp (so the function as a whole returns zero or more doubles -- I won't ask you what possessed you to use `double` as a representation of hours and minutes instead of xs:time or something more plausible, that's between you and your engineering conscience.

```
declare function local:get_multi_track_sequence_time( 
    $msgSeq as element()*
) as xs:double* {
for $entry in $msgSeq

where $entry/self::SEQUENCE
         [TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID']
      /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
         [TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID']
      /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
         [TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID']
      /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
         [TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS' and MODE='VALID']
      /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
         [TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI']
      /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
         [TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI']
      /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
         [TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI']
      /following-sibling::*[1]/self::SEQUENCE
         [TAG='2900' and FIELD='MULTI_CHAN_IND' and MODE='MULTI'] 
return data($entry/TIME)
};
```

When the sequence of SEQUENCE elements shown in the question is passed to this function, it returns the number 14.05.

Comment: Thank you @c-m-sperberg-mcqueen for your helpful & detailed suggestions. I still experienced problems so have taken these in conjunction with the first answer to produce a self contained test function (see my original question where it appears in the update), with sample data, to test the `following-sibling::` matches. Your suggestion works if I strip out the `following-sibling::` matches so that the function returns only the `TRACK_STATUS/VALID` matches. BTW - I have no control over the time format as scalar time is what the system provides in the input XML.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this throws an error is that your function is not returning anything (empty sequence), but it is declared as returning an `xs:double`. If you run your query under [Saxon](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/), you get this more informative error message:

> An empty sequence is not allowed as the result of function
>   local:get_multi_track_sequence_time()

So then the next question is, should your function always return a double, or should you change the `as` declaration to allow the possibility that it will return an empty sequence? Similarly, the way your query is written, it could conceivably return multiple results, one for each row that satisfies your `where` clause. That would cause a type error too. Do you want to allow that?

Even in the case where the `where` clause is only satisfied for one row, you will end up returning multiple timestamps with

```
return data($row/SEQUENCE/TIME)
```

because this selects every `<TIME>` element that is a child of `<SEQUENCE>` that is a child of an element in `$row`. Instead, you want

```
return data($row/SEQUENCE[1]/TIME)
```

Similarly, regarding `following-sibling::`, don't forget to use `[1]` to indicate that you are trying to access the *next* sibling, not just any following sibling:

```
.../following-sibling::SEQUENCE[1][TAG='2900' and FIELD='TRACK_STATUS'
  and MODE='VALID']...
```

That should give you better performance, as well as making sure your `where` clause doesn't give false positives.

Comment: Thank you @LarsH for the suggestions. I have taken these in conjunction with the second answer to produce a self contained test function, with sample data, to test the following-sibling matches.